# Is there a way to set a default cursor type in PDO (specifically PDO_SQLSRV)?

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, pdo

So, annoyingly, the PDO_SQLSRV driver from Microsoft returns -1 on any rowCount() call from a SELECT query with non-scrollable cursors.

Further adding to the annoyance, the default cursor type is _FORWARD, meaning that I am seemingly having to add attributes to every prepared statement where I may need to get a row count back (in this app, that's A LOT) as below. This is unacceptable, as some of the database engines we will be using do not support scrollable cursors.

```
$pdo->prepare("SELECT x FROM y", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR, PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
```

Curiously this does not seem to work with PDO::query()...

***Edit:***
As below, I've also tried PDO::setAttribute() and adding the option to PDO::__construct(), but neither throw exceptions or errors, or seem to actually do anything!

My question to you all is: **is there a way to set the default cursor type to CURSOR_SCROLL?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR, PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL);
```

?

Also you can extend base PDO class with your own, with `prepare` method overriden:

```
class MyPdo extends PDO
{
    public function prepare($statement, $options = array())
    {
        if (empty($options)) $options = array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL);
        return parent::prepare($statement, $options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention - have tried this one, along with in PDO::__construct(, array()) but neither seem to have any effect.

Comment: Yeah nice. Didn't even think of that :O